# 'git status' shows incorrect commit count from origin/master

Tags: git

In my local repo, I ran the following commnands:

- `git checkout -b localBranch origin/master` < created a new branch
  to track the remote branch 'master'
- `git status` < says up-to-date
- `git reset --hard HEAD~30` < I was facing some build issues. This is where the build doesnt fail. Some other developer has checked in with some issues it seems. I
- `git status` < Now, this says that I'm behind 36
  commits from origin/master

I was expecting that it would show that I'm behind by 30 commits but it says 36 commits. Why is that? Does it count the commits from merged branches also or am I missing something else here?

Note: There are multiple other branches in remote and few got merged into master branch.

Comment: Neat question. How many merges into master? 6 perhaps?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe. It is a huge tree with lots of long branches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By running `git reset --hard HEAD~30`, you reverted to the 30-th parent of `HEAD`. But if you used branching, there may be more than 30 commits between `HEAD` and `HEAD~30`.

For example:

```
*   501fe6f (origin/master) Merge branch 'master' into HEAD
|\  
| * 24c80b0 foo
* | 69d4fad foo
|/  
* 93d4461 (HEAD -> master) foo
* 566ba14 foo
* 97f38e0 old
```

The local `master` is `origin/master~2`, but there are 3 commits between them. And `git status` shows `3 commits behind`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Consider the same tree above with pointers in the same place but lets say, **I've 19 commits after 24c80b0 in that branch**. Now, will the status be `behind by 22 commits` for the master branch? If yes, can you explain why? Because, I would have ran `reset HEAD~2` but it will show `behind 22 commits` where I wont care about the commits from the merged branches (coz, the merged branches could be some feature development with lots of temporary commits).

Comment: `git status` will show you the number of commits between your local branch and the remote-tracking one. If you have an unrelated branch starting at 24c80b0, then the commits from that branch won't be used. If you have commits in a branch starting at 24c80b0 but that has been merged in `master`, then these commits will be counted.

Comment: Ya.. I was asking about a merged branch only as it is shows in the tree above. So, for the scenario in my comment above, the status would be `22 commits behind` even-though I did reset  only for `HEAD~2`. Am I right?

Comment: If I understand correctly your explanations, yes you are right.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it count the commits from merged branches

Of course it does.

Every commit that can be reached from `origin/master` and cannot be reached by local `master` is a commit you don't have.

You'll have all 36 of them (including the branches merged in `origin/master`) when you merge `origin/master` into `master`.